How to handle new tab operation in cypress?
Here is my scenario: I am accessing button from which is opening in new tab. I need to test this redirection and perform few operations on . Seems this redirection is designed with javascript. As I don't see tag with href= and target="_blank" attributes in DOM. How to handle this scenario to automate?
Here is the dom for "view report"
<span class="mat-mdc-button-persistent-ripple mdc-button__ripple"></span>
<span class="mdc-button__label">View report</span>
<span class="mat-mdc-focus-indicator"></span>
<span class="mat-mdc-button-touch-target"></span>
<span class="mat-ripple mat-mdc-button-ripple"></span>


Please do repeat a question that has already been closed. Instead, you should improve the original question - I guess you need to show some code and make it a reproducible example so that it meets the guidelines of this site.

This question is similar to: Cypress opens link in new tab regardless removed/changed target. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You may not be looking far enough for the href.
From the documented examples here, there is a parent <a> above the exact same elements you posted.
<a _ngcontent-ng-c1927635254="" mat-button="" 
  href="https://www.google.com/" 
  target="_blank" 
  mat-ripple-loader-class-name="mat-mdc-button-ripple" 
  class="mdc-button mat-mdc-button mat-unthemed mat-mdc-button-base">

  <span class="mat-mdc-button-persistent-ripple mdc-button__ripple"></span>
  <span class="mdc-button__label">Link</span>
  <span class="mat-mdc-focus-indicator"></span>
  <span class="mat-mdc-button-touch-target"></span>
  <span class="mat-ripple mat-mdc-button-ripple"></span>
</a>

The spans you posted are just to augment the link with ripple effect, etc but the functionality comes from the anchor element.
If the link is in the same domain, you can navigate it as follows,
let link;  
cy.contains('span', 'Link')  // find the label
  .parent('a')              // go to the anchor
  .invoke('attr', 'href')
  .then(val => link = val)  // save for checking

cy.contains('span', 'Link')
  .parent('a')
  .then($link => $link.attr('target', '_self'))  // prevent new tab
  .click()

cy.location('pathname').should('eq', link)

If the link is external to your application, you will need to continue testing inside cy.origin() to avoid security issues.
For example, the link on the reference page is google.com.
cy.visit('https://material.angular.io/components/button/overview');

cy.contains('span', 'Link')
  .parent('a')
  .then($link => $link.attr('target', '_self'))  // prevent new tab
  .click()

cy.origin('https://www.google.com', () => {

  // confirm search feature on google page
  cy.get('input[type="submit"][aria-label="Google Search"]')
})


I do not have  tag for this redirection. It's handled using JavaScript event

If you are using MDC, then there will be an <a> tag, you're just not seeing it in the DOM.
